# PATCH request, always get 404 Not Found response

Tags: rest-api, integration, patch

I am trying to update a value on my Salesforce record and integrate the date in another system using the Rest API. I am unable to do this using the PATCH request workaround in apex.

```
Booking__c reservation = [Select id,name,end__c,Impala_id__c from Booking__c 
                              where id=:reservationId];
DateTime dt = reservation.End__c;
dt = dt.addDays(1);
Integer endTime= dt.getTime().intValue()/1000;

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + api_key);//some api key value
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override','PATCH');

req.setEndpoint('https://api.getimpala.com/v2/hotel/'+hotel_id+'/booking/'
                    +reservation.Impala_id__c+'?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
req.setBody('{"end":'+endTime+'}');
req.setMethod('POST');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res2 = http.send(req);
system.debug('status is: '+res2.getStatus());
system.debug('status is: '+res2.getStatusCode());
```

I tried using both the options (1-using header and 2-appending in url). whereas in postman this is working fine which means endpoint is up and running.
[image]

Comment: Please, try to set ```req.setMethod('POST);``` before ```req.setHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override','PATCH');```. That might be a case, because header worked fine for me for PATCH endpoints.

Comment: The version with params in link will not work for you, because it works only for requests from SF to another SF org.

Comment: Can you add the exact response from both the Apex callout and the POSTMAN callout to review?

Answer (score 1):

HttpRequest doesn't support PATCH as the method. From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm#apex_System_HttpRequest_setMethod):

> Possible values for the method type include:
>
> DELETE 
>   
>  GET 
>   
>  HEAD 
>   
>  POST 
>   
>  PUT
>   
>  TRACE

Setting `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header to `PATCH` is a workaround some services support if a client can't issue a PATCH request. Docs for [getimpala.com APIs](https://docs.getimpala.com/) do not mention this option nor do they mention appending `_HttpMethod=PATCH` to the endpoint as a possibility.

Recommendation: send a POST request to a proxy that lives outside of Salesforce, then have the proxy rewrite POST to PATCH, send the PATCH request to getimpala.com, grab the response and send the response back to Salesforce. Lots of proxies can do this, e.g. here's how it works with [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/9-5/traffic-management/lb-layer7/http-rewrite/).